# In C, why does alloc struct set pointers to NULL, but not directly alloc char?

Tags: c, struct, null, dynamic-memory-allocation

## **Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
    char* word;
    struct item* next;
} item;

int main(void)
{
    /*using pointer to char*/
    char* test;
    test = calloc(4, sizeof(char));

    if(test==NULL) printf("NULL\n");
    else printf("NOT NULL\n");

    /*using pointer to struct*/
    item* p = calloc(4, sizeof(item));
    
    if(p->word==NULL) printf("NULL\n"); 
    else printf("NOT NULL\n");

    if(p->next==NULL) printf("NULL\n");
    else printf("NOT NULL\n");

    return 0;
}
```

## **Output**

```
NOT NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I was surprised by this behavior. I believe the reason might be that the elements of the char* test are all set to '\0' when using calloc, but the pointer variable *test* itself is not NULL as it's now pointing to an array of '\0' characters. In fact, I would say it was never NULL as it was never initialized and therefore, it was holding garbage values beforehand.

However, I don't fully appreciate as to why both pointers in my structure (item* next and char* word) are being set to NULL?

Comment: The members of your allocated structure (even if they are pointers) will have all their bytes/bits set to zero by the `calloc` call, because that's what `calloc` does. [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) Further, on (almost) all platforms, `NULL` is the same as `(void*)0`.

Comment: "*but the pointer variable `test` itself is not NULL*" Yes, and the same thing is true of the pointer `p`. The pointer `p` itself is not NULL. The *contents* of what `p` points to have been zeroed by the calloc. Likewise, the *contents* of what `test` points to have been zeroed.

Comment: ... but note that C does not require that all-bits-zero is a null pointer representation.  That happens to be a pretty common characteristic of C language implementations, but it is not a universal one.  Therefore, it is not safe to assume that your program will print the same output on every C implementation (even assuming that the `calloc()` calls never fail).